# Regex, select all not between square brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large file of strings containing a lot of "tags" [[STRING]]. I've been trying to use notepad++ to extract these tags using the find and replace with regex enabled. So far all I've managed is to match the contents of [[STRING]].

```
\[\[([^]]+)\]\]
```

Can anyone provide me with regex for a search and replace that would leave me with just a list of [[STRING]]'s on new lines?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need `[[STRING]]` or `STRING` to keep?

Comment: Put up a snip of your file.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the brackets but losing them doesn't bother me.

Comment: I suggested two expressions for both the scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alternation of your pattern with a negated version:

```
(\[\[[^]]+]])|(?:(?!\[\[[^]]+]]).)+
 ^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And replace with `$1\n`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jR4dG0/1). The *`.` matches newline* should be *enabled*. If the performance is not great with this one, use an unrolled version:

```
(\[\[[^]]+]])|[^[]*(?:\[(?!\[)[^[]*)*
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK2qZ0/1)

The `(?:(?!\[\[[^]]+]]).)+` is a tempered greedy token that is working as a negated character class, but with sequences of characters (matches any text other than "abc").

[image]

Then, just remove all empty lines (*Edit* -> *Line Operations* -> *Remove Empty Lines*).

Well, you could also use a simpler regex like `(\[\[[^]]+]])|.` to replace with `$1\n`, but it would add too many linebreaks. Actually, that should not be a problem as you can later remove all the empty lines. Just use whatever works best for you.

Comment: I added a faster, unrolled, regex version.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple
Find `(?s).*?(?:(\[\[[^\[\]]+\]\])|$)`
Replace `$1\n`

```
 (?s)
 .*? 
 (?:
      (                             # (1 start)
           \[\[
           [^\[\]]+ 
           \]\]
      )                             # (1 end)
   |  
      $ 
 )
```

---

*[Yours](https://regex101.com/r/lK6rQ1/1) is not as efficient as [mine](https://regex101.com/r/sK2qZ0/1). – Wiktor Stribiżew*

```
Regex1:   (?s).*?(?:(\[\[[^\[\]]+\]\])|$)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.29 s,   290.80 ms,   290799 µs


Regex2:   (\[\[[^]]+]])|[^[]*(?:\[(?!\[)[^[]*)*
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    0.68 s,   677.31 ms,   677309 µs
```

---

*This should work also: `(?s).*?(\[\[[^\[\]]+\]\]|$)`. I think you don't have to put it into non-capturing group. – ccf*

Works, but makes no difference.

```
Regex1:   (?s).*?(?:(\[\[[^\[\]]+\]\])|$)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.58 s,   580.74 ms,   580737 µs


Regex2:   (?s).*?(\[\[[^\[\]]+\]\]|$)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.59 s,   589.32 ms,   589323 µs
```

Comment: [Yours](https://regex101.com/r/lK6rQ1/1) is not as efficient as [mine](https://regex101.com/r/sK2qZ0/1).

Comment: Lazy matching is not efficient with longer inputs, it must be unrolled.

Comment: This should work also: `(?s).*?(\[\[[^\[\]]+\]\]|$)`. I think you don't have to put it into non-capturing group.

Comment: @ccf - Added a note about your regex, the cluster makes no difference to an engine at all. For me, I never put anchors in capture groups..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The length of the input is not an issue in this case. `.*?` tells the engine to find the first `[[` and that's what it does. There is nothing faster.

Comment: The lazy dot matching pattern is not that powerful as it may seem. [*Some regex performance guides will advise you to be wary when using the lazy quantifier  because it does its own kind of backtracking. It consumes one character at a time and then attempts to match the rest of the regex. If that fails, it “backtracks” and moves the cursor one character over and repeats. This can sometimes make the lazy star not at all faster or even slower than the greedy star.*](https://www.loggly.com/blog/five-invaluable-techniques-to-improve-regex-performance/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That might be good general advice. But in cases like this there is nothing to make it backtrack, it has a clear path all the way to the end. Engines know this and optimize accordingly.

Comment: I agree there is nothing to backtrack because this is lazy pattern *expansion* (the lazy pattern is skipped and all the subsequent are checked, if no match found, the lazy subpattern matches 1 character if it can and again all the subsequent patterns are checked - this loop may be substantial in case the rightmost subpatterns find a match at the end of the string. That is why with longer input lazy patterns are not efficient, but with shorter they "win".

Comment: @ WiktorStribiżew - `all the subsequent patterns are checked` Actually, in this case the very next `[` is found. It is irrelevant  there is a `.*?` when searching. It's a directive that allows `[` to be consumed if not the beginning of  `[[..]]`. That is the loop, the only thing's checked.